# Python Bubble Sorting with an array of objects

Tags: python, arrays, poker

I'm attempting to sort a "hand" array of card objects for a texas-hold-em game in Python, where the card objects hold three values: strings for suits, strings/integers for values, and integers for their "ranking" when checking for straights.

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, val, rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = val
        self.rank = rank

    def show(self):
        print("{} of {}s".format(self.value, self.suit))
```

I also have a class for each player, who has a "pocket" of two cards, and a seven-card hand that includes the pocket and the board.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.pocket = []
        self.hand = []
        self.temp = []
```

To check for a straight flush, I feel like I need to have my self.hand array sorted by rank so I can easily roll through the suit/rank values to see if that miraculous hand is there. Since it's such a small data set I elected for a bubble sort, which I implemented by

```
        self.hand.append(Card("Diamond", 5, 5))
        self.hand.append(Card("Spade", "Ace", 1))
        self.hand.append(Card("Diamond", "Queen", 12))
        self.hand.append(Card("Diamond", 10, 10))
        self.hand.append(Card("Diamond", "King", 13))
        self.hand.append(Card("Diamond", 9, 9))
        self.hand.append(Card("Diamond", "Jack", 11))

        for x in self.hand:
            self.temp.append(x.rank)

        n = len(self.temp)

        for i in range(n - 1):
            for j in range(0, n - i - 1):
                if(self.temp[j] > self.temp[j + 1]):
                    self.hand[j], self.hand[j + 1] = self.hand[j + 1], self.hand[j]
        
        for i in self.hand:
            i.show()
```

This bubble sort algorithm worked with a set of integers in another program, but when I display the hand here it remains unsorted. There are no error messages. Any idea where I'm wrong?

Comment: you are not sorting the temp list alongside the hand list.

Comment: And why use bubble sort in the first place? just use `self.hand.sort(key = lamdba x: x.rank)`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to swap the values in `self.temp`. Just add this inside the inner loop:

```py
self.temp[j], self.temp[j + 1] = self.temp[j + 1], self.temp[j]
```

Also, unless you're trying to implement bubble sort, you should directly use `.sort()` method, which would be more optimal

Comment: Thank you, I'll use that .sort() method going forward. Fairly new at this point